# How to run Clojure tests from clj (not from lein neither boot)?

Tags: testing, clojure

In a project with the traditional lein project structure, how can I use simply `clj` to run the tests in the test folder?

**Update:**
After the mention the REPL, I would like to clarify I'm trying that from the System shell with the `clj` command. Not from the REPL, neither `lein` nor `boot`.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the test-runner from Cognitect. https://github.com/cognitect-labs/test-runner

Once you add the alias, you should be able to run the tests via:

```
clj -Atest
```

If you need to configure the directory,

```
clj -Atest -d path/to/tests
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run tests from the repl:

```clj
; all tests
(clojure.test/run-all-tests)
; all tests in one file
(clojure.test/run-tests 'com.myproject.test.routes.api_test)
; one particular test 
(clojure.test/test-vars [#'com.myproject.test.routes.api_test/id-test])
```

You can find some additional information in [official documentation](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html).
And it's very convenient to run tests with [cursive](https://cursive-ide.com/userguide/testing.html) plugin in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Unfortunately, you need to `require` all the namespaces you want to test before `clojure.test/run-all-tests` picks them up, so this is not as easy as it seems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I clarified I'm not interested in the REPL solution.